# make modules_install restarts configuration process for cross compile

Tags: cross-compiling, kernel-module, beagleboneblack

I am cross compile kernel and modules for my Beaglebone Black on my laptop ubuntu 14.04, After I typed the `make modules_install`, the configure process restart. The last step is the wrong way.
the steps:

1,  `cp arch/arm/configs/bb.org_defconfig defconfig_LQ`

2,  `make ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=arm-linux-gnueabi- menuconfig`

```
`load defconfig_LQ` 

 do some modification based on your needs

`save defconfig_LQ`

`cp defconfig_LQ arch/arm/configs/beaglebone_defconfig`
```

3,  `make ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=arm-linux-gnueabi- beaglebone_defconfig` generate the `.config`

4,  `make ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=arm-linux-gnueabi- uImage dtbs` compile the kernel

5,   `make ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=arm-linux-gnueabi-  modules` compile the modules

6,   `sudo make modules_install` install modules to default path

Comment: Missing information: which steps you used to compile kernel and modules.

Comment: @unixsmurf how about now?

Comment: Much better :) Final comment - this does not matter for compiling the kernel, but for building anything else, you should be using arm-linux-gnueabihf- for beaglebone black.

Comment: @unixsmurf http://wiki.beyondlogic.org/index.php/BeagleBoneBlack_Building_Kernel  http://elinux.org/Building_BBB_Kernel  https://eewiki.net/display/linuxonarm/BeagleBone+Black           but I got the info from these sites, I tried all of them, they all work.

Comment: As I said, it does not matter for the kernel - but gnueabihf is the one exposing hardware floating-point. Binaries built with the gnueabi toolchain will not execute correctly on an ARMv7 Linux distribution such as Ubuntu or Fedora, or the Debian armhf port. Both gnueabi and a gnueabihf cross compilers exist in Ubuntu.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if you use the

`make ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=arm-linux-gnueabi- INSTALL_MOD_PATH=/path/to/target modules`

then you need

`make ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=arm-linux-gnueabi- INSTALL_MOD_PATH=/path/to/target modules_install`

instead of `make modules_install`